# How are void methods popped from the call stack?

Tags: java, callstack

This might seems to be a silly question. I tried different resources to understand how a void method is being poped out from a call stack. I am not able to figure that out, Seeking for help. Thanks in advance.

A Simple example -

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 int sum = sum(2,3);
 System.out.println(sum);
}
public static int sum(int first, int second){
   return first + second;
}
```

So for above, example call stack would allocate two stack frames containing method calls details as below - 
[image]

Comment: They follow the same method as non-void methods. Just think of void methods having a `return;` at the end. They still have a return statement it is just implicit. So they are popped off the stack in the same way.

Comment: If we are putting an explicit return statement that make sense. Should I assume that there is a return statement?

Comment: There is most certainly a `return` instruction in the compiled bytecode.

Comment: @SeanBright out of curiosity, Is there any way we can make be sure of it?

Comment: You can look at the bytecode. There are tools to do it and most IDEs have a bytecode viewer of some kind.

Comment: Thank you @SeanBright I would check that for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification-Java SE 8 Edition [2.11.8]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/):

> ...the *return* instruction is used to return from methods declared to be void, instance initialization methods, and class or interface initialization methods.

Thus the bytecode for the two following methods is identical (as viewed with [BCV](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer)), namely a single `return` instruction:

```
public void test() {
    return;
}

public void test() {
}
```